# Select image and upload to server android

Tags: android, image, file, upload, retrofit

I want to upload the image to server by selecting from gallery

Opening gallery by

```
val pickPhoto = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startForResult.launch(pickPhoto)
```

And then activity result

```
val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
{ result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //  you will get result here in result.data
        if(result.data!=null){
            val f=File(result.data.toString())
            println(f.absolutePath)
        }
    }

}
```

However I think the file is not correct.

My api call is like

```
@Multipart
@PUT
fun uploadFile(
    @Url url:String,
    @Part("file") name: RequestBody,
    @Part filepart: MultipartBody.Part
): Response<String>
```

And I am calling this as

```
val fileToUpload: MultipartBody.Part =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName())
        val filename: RequestBody =
            file.getName().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        Api.uploadFile(uploadUrl,filename,fileToUpload)
```

Its a stream upload

Comment: `val f=File(result.data.toString())` That makes no sense. You got an uri. Use that uri directly. You cannot use it for the File class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to URI only as it was not getting the correct absolute path of file

to retrive the absolute path

```
private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentURI: Uri): String {
    val result: String
    val cursor: Cursor? = requireContext().contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null)
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath().toString()
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
        result = cursor.getString(idx)
        cursor.close()
    }
    return result
}
```

The activity result

```
val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
{ result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //  you will get result here in result.data
        if(result.data!=null){
            val f=File(getRealPathFromURI(result.data?.data!!))
            viewModel.uploadCheque(f)
        }
    }

}
```